# move to sdcard with minSdk=4 (Android1.6)

Tags: android, app2sd

I want to add a new feature, move2SDcard available only on API8 (Android2.2) but making minSdkversion="4". So, I change the Android jar file loaded in eclipse by (project prop -> Android ) and select Android 2.2 Project compiles and runs. 
Is this a good way to add new apis specific to new versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for minSdkversion you need to specify the minimal api level with which you app runs with no problems, in you case api level 8. If you say min sdk 4 that means that your app will be able to be installed on phone with api level 5 and in app with api level 5 I think your app would NOT be able to work correctly.

with Android 2.2 it goes minSdkversion="8" (API level 8) [FROYO](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#FROYO)

here are some platform highlights http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2-highlights.html

take a look to the statistics of the market and you will understand that most of the apps are above API 8 http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html